# Get image src from xml using xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
......
  <itemBody>
    <div class="grid-row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <associateInteraction shuffle="false" maxAssociations="0" minAssociations="0" responseIdentifier="RESPONSE">
          <prompt/>
          <simpleAssociableChoice fixed="false" showHide="show" matchMax="0" matchMin="0" identifier="choice_1">Bolbasoor<img src="001.png" alt="001" width="100%"/></simpleAssociableChoice>
          <simpleAssociableChoice fixed="false" showHide="show" matchMax="0" matchMin="0" identifier="choice_2">Pikachu<img src="Pikachu-the-ultimate-pokemon-fan-club-11690553-450-413.jpg" alt="Pikachu the-ultimate-pokemon-fan-club-11690553-450-413" width="100%"/></simpleAssociableChoice>
          <simpleAssociableChoice fixed="false" showHide="show" matchMax="0" matchMin="0" identifier="choice_3">Squeroo<img src="007.png" alt="007" width="100%"/></simpleAssociableChoice>
          <simpleAssociableChoice fixed="false" showHide="show" matchMax="0" matchMin="0" identifier="choice_4">Chalmender<img src="2438704-1202149925_t.png" alt="2438704 1202149925_t" width="100%"/></simpleAssociableChoice>
        </associateInteraction>
      </div>
    </div>
  </itemBody>
......
```

and I need extract for every Simple Associable Choice (Identifier, Text and Source Image) 
like this:

```
<param name="hotspot0" value="choice_1::Bolbasoor::001.png">
```

So I'm using XSLT to extract the identifer and the text but I can't extract the Source Image. How I can do that?

```
<xsl:variable name="choices" as="element(qti:simpleAssociableChoice)*" select="qw:filter-visible(qti:simpleAssociableChoice)"/>
<param name="hotspot_count" value="{count($choices)}"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$choices">
    <xsl:variable name="content" as="node()*">
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <param name="hotspot{position()-1}" value="{@identifier}::{$content}::Here I need to source image"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source image is the `src` attribute of the `img` element, which is a child of `simpleAssociableChoice`, so the expression I think you want is `img/@src`.

```
<param name="hotspot{position()-1}" value="{@identifier}::{$content}::{img/@src}"/>
```

Or perhaps it should be `qti:img/@src` if your actual XML has namespaces.

```
<param name="hotspot{position()-1}" value="{@identifier}::{$content}::{qti:img/@src}"/>
```

Comment: it give an empty string

<param name="hotspot0" value="choice_1::Bolbasoor::">

Comment: Does you actual XML have namespaces? I've made an edit to my answer to hopefully handle this.